# How match a regex multiline in java?

Tags: regex, newline

I have this string with a new line in it

And it does not match anything in a new line `"W https://stadt.muenchen.de/infos/portrait-referat- bildung-sport.html"`

This is my regex `\bW\s((www\.\s*|https:\/\/)?[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+(\/[\w\-.\/?%&=]*)?)`
https://regex101.com/r/KEACmP/1

I want that the full link is matching. So that the regex is multiline and stops there then

So I want "W [https://stadt.muenchen.de/infos/portrait-referatbildung-sport.html"](https://stadt.muenchen.de/infos/portrait-referatbildung-sport.html%22)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in addfition to your regex i have added `\s*.*?\.html`
`\s*` will match new line or any spaces
`\bW\s((www\.\s*|https:\/\/)?[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+(\/[\w\-.\/?%&=]*)?)\s*.*?\.html`

Comment: thank you, with this regex it worked for me (just changed that the multiline not mandatory)

\bW\s((www\.\s*|https:\/\/)?[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+(\/[\w\-.\/?%&=]*)?)(?:\s*.*?\.html)?